# Calculate the probability given both the 2 independent events happen

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics

Probability of winning a game of soccer, given 1 of the 10 players is Messi, is = 0.8.
Probability of winning the same game, given 1 of the 10 players is Ronaldo is = 0.6.
What is the probability of winning if both Ronaldo and Messi are in the team?

So, using notations -

```
Given,
P(Win | Messi playing) = 0.8 and 
P(Win | Ronaldo playing) = 0.6

What is P(Win | both playing) = ?
```

Can you give me some directions on how to solve the problem? (Assuming it is solvable)

**EDIT**

Here is another version of the problem -

*Probability of rain is 0.8 if temperature drops more than 5 degree. Probability of rain is 0.6 if pressure drops 10%. What is the probability of rain if temperature drops more than 5 and pressure drops 10%? Assume temperature drop and pressure drops are independent events.*

Comment: What have you tried?  What assumptions must you make.

Comment: I do not have any formal training on mathematics (other than what I learnt in high schools over 20 yrs back). Initially, I thought it will be just 0.8x0.6 - but I realized it is wrong. I am willing to try on my own but I need some directions.

Comment: Compute the probability you LOSE with both players... then the probability you win is 1 minus the probability you lose.

Comment: P(Loss|Messi) = 1 - 0.8 = 0.2. P(Loss|Ronaldo) = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4. But how to find P(Loss| Both Ronaldo+Messi) = ?

Comment: Most games of soccer rely on teamwork.  I do not think that independence here is a fair assumption to make... but if we were to assume for example that Messi has an $0.8$ chance of scoring two goals (*and an 0.2 chance of scoring none*), and Ronaldo has an $0.6$ chance of scoring two goals (*and 0.4 chance of scoring none*), all other teammates of theirs always score zero goals... and these are independent of one another... and the other team always scores exactly one goal... then the calculation here would be "The opposite probability than the chance that neither scored"

Comment: That would be $1 - 0.2\times 0.4$.  Now... again... this seems like a *terrible* assumption to make for soccer... and especially for the original phrasing of the problem.  In the original phrasing it was about "probability of winning", not "probability of making a goal" and so it is unclear how exactly the events could be independent... how to resolve Messi's event coming up as "winning" while Ronaldo's event coming up as "not winning"?  Those don't sound independent at all.

Comment: For how I would have interpreted the original problem, I would have said that there is not nearly enough information and any available assumptions are far too extreme to be valid.  It can not be answered.

Comment: That's a great explanation. So, let me add one more information to the original problem. The probability of the team to win (without Messi or Ronaldo playing) is 0.5. When Messi or Ronaldo plays, all the other factors remain equal. So, I have P(win) = 0.5. Does it make the problem any more approachable?